# FastAPI: Combine ORM and dataclass

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi, python-dataclasses

I am trying to use dataclass in combination with fastapi. I want to use the same dataclass for fastapi (json-serialisation) *and* orm-database model.

my `model.py` looks like this:

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry

reg = registry()


@reg.mapped_as_dataclass(dataclass_callable=dataclass)
class WatchListDec:
    __tablename__ = "Movie"
    id: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    title: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(length=50))
    storyline: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(length=255))
    active: Mapped[bool]
    # Private Attribute

    @staticmethod
    def url() -> str:
        return "/movie/list/"
```

my `database.py` looks like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./movielist.db"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
```

my `view.py` looks like this:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

import models
import database

app = FastAPI()


@app.post(models.WatchListDec.url())
def add_movies(movie: models.WatchListDec):
    db = database.SessionLocal()
    db.add(movie)
    return movie.title

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

When I now run a POST-request I receive Code 422 because the `id` field is missing:

```
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body"
            ],
            "msg": "__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'",
            "type": "type_error"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way here to tell fastapi that it should ignore the id-field? Is there a solution with another ORM which can be combined with `pydantic` or `dataclass`? Or do I need to solve it similar to the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66372199/)?

Comment: Example data for a POST-request: `{"title": "Some movie", "storyline": "some story", "active": true}`

Comment: Not an answer to this particular question, but you might want to check out [`SQLModel`](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com). It uses a single class (inheriting from both Pydantic and SQLAlchemy) to represent a table/model for both DB interaction and API parsing/validation.

Comment: Did you find a clean solution?

Comment: Off-topic: same data shape for the API and the database is rarely great. What happens when you have to support 2 versions of the API at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You may assign a default value to `id`:

```py
id: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, default=999)
```

The default value is a place holder. You must remove it before saving to database.

---

The 2nd way is to declare a 'brother' model specifically for creation:

```py
@dataclass
class WatchListDecCreate:
    title: str
    storyline: str
    active: bool
```

And cast the dataclass instance to a SQLAlchemy instance by a regular python way.